# c++ - Reference Counting garbage collection

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, reference-counting

Consider a simple class:

```
class MyInt {
public:
    MyInt();

    MyInt(const char *num);
};
```

I want to intergrate reference counting design pattern in to the class, which means i need to keep track of how much pointers point to an instance of this class. I need to implement it in this class only or create a different class and inherit it.

Given this example code i want to clear any allocated memory of the program:

```
int main() {
    MyInt*a = new MyInt("10");
    a = new MyInt("20");
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

**My Tries**

I tried operator oveloading of '=' and adding referenceCount member:

```
MyInt &MyInt::operator=(const MyInt* right) {
    MyInt*left = this;
    *this = right;
    left->referenceCount -= 1;
    if (left->referenceCount == 0) {
        delete (left);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

But this does not work because we assign pointer of the class to another pointer.

Also tried to override the new and delete operators but can't seem to make it work and keep track of the number of pointer to an instance.

As it seems i need to implement four things: copy constructor, operator new, operator delete and operator =.

How can i effectivly keep track of the pointers and clear unpointed memory automaticly?

Comment: Use `std::shared_ptr`.  It has this built in.

Comment: If you want an intrusive pointer, look at boost. Even if you do not use boost, you can copy the pattern. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html

Comment: Looks like you have very limited knowledge of the topic, and topic is too broad for SO. Just google for intrusive smart pointers.

Comment: @Fabio why use something not standard, when the standard already provides the functionality?

Comment: @gsamaras I need to implement on my own in this exercise.

Comment: @DannyHambourg, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Peter Ruderman A university exercise.

Comment: @gsamaras, pretty much everything which is in the modern STL has been first battle tested in boost. shared_ptr is one of these features that made into the STL, while intrusive_ptr did not. There are pros and cons in use of invasive vs non-invasive pointers and plenty of discussions on the web about it. I think a re-discussing It here would be beyond the scope of the question. Regarding the specific question, I simply mentioned intrusive_ptr as a possible design, which seems to me closer to the stated objectives of the question.

Comment: @Danny, note however that reference counting for automatic deallocation is one thing, implementing a garbage collector is a much more complex problem. It may require internally the use of smart pointers, but there is much more to do.

Comment: @Fabio I think it would be an overkill for the OP to follow this design. I see your point though, it's good that several options are in the table.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) does exactly this. From the ref:

> Manages the storage of a pointer, providing a limited
>   **garbage-collection** facility, possibly sharing that management with
>   other objects. [...] Once all shared_ptr objects that share *ownership*
>   over a pointer have released this ownership, the managed object is
>   deleted.

so I suggest you use this instead.

Comment: I need the example code to work exactly as it is. This adds wrapping to the code.

Comment: @DannyHambourg The language doesn't allow what you are trying to do without adding a layer of abstraction. It's not possible to overload the assignment operator for a raw pointer.

Comment: @DannyHambourg Even though your pointer is to a custom type you can't overload operators for it.  All pointers are considered the same (over simplification) and all operations on them use built in operators that can't be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a pointer, so assigning to `a` will not involve `MyInt::opterator=` in any way. There is no way to detect when a pointer to `T` is assigned to by overloading `T`'s operators. To do this, you would need to design a `class` type that behaves like a pointer. Then you could properly track when the pointer might leak an object and properly delete it. Fortunately for you, the standard library already provides this `class`. It's [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Here is your example modified to use `std::shared_ptr` :

```
#include <memory>

struct InfInt {
    InfInt(const char *) {}
};

int main() 
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<InfInt>("10");
    a = std::make_shared<InfInt>("20"); // the previous `a` is deleted

    // The object pointed to by `a` is automatically deleted when 
    //  the last reference to it goes out of scope
    return 0;   
}
```